# Upload file to S3 using perl and AWS cli

Tags: perl, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Hy Guys

I am trying to upload file using perl and AWS CLI.
Here is the uploading file to S3 part from my script.

```
 if (-d "$destdir/$agent") {
            if (aws s3 $ogg_file   s3://recordings)
        } else {
               print STDERR "Failed to move\n";
        }
```

or is there any easy way to do that?

- **debian_version 7.11**
- **perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2)**
- **python2.7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already [PAWS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws) which is a Perl SDK for AWS.

Since you are using awscli as mention by Dave you have to use system or backtics (``) command to run it since it is a external program.

I already have created a small script to perform aws operation using cli in past. For reference you can have a look at it. 
https://github.com/rai-gaurav/perl-toolkit/tree/master/AWS

You can use 'cp' or 'sync' for your job.
You have to run something like-

```
my $cmd = "aws s3 sync " . $input_location . " s3://" . $bucket_name . "/" . $folder_name . "/";
$upload_output = `$cmd`;
print ($upload_output);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems very unlikely that you're using a library which makes `aws` into a Perl command. It seems far more likely that `aws` is an external program that you are trying to run. In which case, you need to run it using Perl's [`system()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function.

```
system('aws', 's3', $ogg_file, 's3://recordings');
```

Note that `system()` has a slightly strange return value. You'll need to read the documentation and, probably, reverse the logic in your `if` statement.